# Spark history server with minIO: getting AmazonHttpClient: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection refused

Tags: scala, docker, apache-spark, docker-compose, minio

I am trying to run Spark History Server with minIO but keep getting

`AmazonHttpClient: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection refused`

Complete exception:

```
20/10/20 09:06:21 INFO AmazonHttpClient: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection refused (Connection refused)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
        at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:384)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:232)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3528)
```

My Docker compose:

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  minio:
    image: minio/minio
    container_name: minio
    volumes:
      - data1-1:/data1
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    environment:
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
    command:  server /data1
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9000/minio/health/live" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 3
  spark-history:
    image: test
    build:
      context: spark-history
    container_name: spark-history
    links:
      - minio
    depends_on:
      - minio
    ports:
      - 18080:18080
    volumes:
      - data2:/data2
    environment:
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
volumes:
  data1-1:
  data2:
```

My Dockerfile for Spark History:

```
ARG SPARK_IMAGE=gcr.io/spark-operator/spark:v3.0.0
FROM ${SPARK_IMAGE}
# Switch to user root so we can add additional jars, packages and configuration files.
USER root

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y coreutils

#USER 1234

#RUN apk --update add coreutils
#RUN mkdir /tmp/spark-events
RUN mkdir -p /etc/hadoop/conf
# Add dependency for hadoop-aws
ADD https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.7.4/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar $SPARK_HOME/jars
# Add hadoop-aws to access Amazon S3
ADD https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.7.7/hadoop-aws-2.7.7.jar $SPARK_HOME/jars
ADD spark-defaults.conf /opt/spark/conf/

ENV SPARK_NO_DAEMONIZE TRUE

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/spark/sbin/start-history-server.sh"]
```

My spark-defaults config:

```
spark.history.fs.logDirectory    s3a://spark-streaming/checkpoint/
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint     http://minio:9000
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access  true
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl         org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem
```

Not sure what I am missing

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-12963 was the issue for me. spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.acces is available only from 2.8.0. To fix the issue, I upgrade the hadoop to 3.2

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the same post in the GitHub. Here is the Reference to the Post if you are still looking for the solution.
Basically you have to add the `minio` dependency in the Docker.

https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/10715